# Not able to append element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I have set 2 image container that shows 2 randomly generated image from an array of elements. When user clicks on either of the 2 randomly generated images, an image pop-up will appear. This generated image pop-up; from a second array of image,  is in relation to what random generated image that has been displayed.

Therefore, this is the right behaviour: 
- random generated image A and image B is shown in the page 1, when user click on image A, image pop-up A1 will be shown else image B1 will be shown when image B is clicked.

***Issue:***

I have managed to achieve the following:

1.) randomly generate 2 images from array A and append it to the initial 2 image container

2.) link array B to items generated in array A

I have set out a console log and was able to see that the element from the  2nd array element is correctly called when i select the randomly generated image from array A

However, at this point in time, I am unable to append the item from array B to the image pop-up in my html body..

Please help

Here is the code:

```js
var BrandNameArray = ["lib/img/Brands/A.png", "lib/img/Brands/B.png", "lib/img/Brands/C.png", "lib/img/Brands/D.png"];

var OfferArray = ["lib/img/Offer/A.png", "lib/img/Offer/B.png", "lib/img/Offer/C.png", "lib/img/Offer/D.png"];
var random_BrandIndex, selectedOffer;

function ShowInitialBrand() {
  $('#BrandWinlist > img').each(function(i, img) {
    random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
    //Assign Variable to generate random Brands
    var Brand = BrandNameArray.splice(random_BrandIndex, 1)[0];
    $(img).attr('src', Brand).show();
  });
}

function selectBrand(flag) {
  selectedOffer = OfferArray[random_BrandIndex];

  console.log("selectedOffer: " + selectedOffer);

  $("#P_Description").html(selectedOffer);
}
```

```css
.GameWinBrand_Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 950px;
  left: 286px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.GameWinBrand_innerScroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.GameWinBrand_Container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.GameWinBrand_Container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #5e5767;
}
.GameWinBrand_Container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #5e5767;
}
.BrandMenu {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!-- The first page where 2 randomly generated images are shown-->
<div class="GameWinBrand_Container">
  <div id="BrandWinlist" class="GameWinBrand_innerScroll">
    <img id="GameBrand_1" style="width:230px; height:230px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" onclick="selectBrand('1');">
    <img id="GameBrand_2" style="width:230px; height:230px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('2');">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The second page that will show the image in relation to the image that has been clicked-->

<div id="BrandDescription" class="BrandMenu" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=9; top:0px; margin:auto;">
  <img id="P_Description" style="position:absolute; width: 1080px; height:762px; top:500px; left:0px; z-index=99;">

</div>
```

Comment: is `random_BrandIndex` a global variable? If not I don't know how it gets it from the function `selectBrand(flag)`

Comment: Yes it is, it declared as a global variable

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set the image URL in the second to show the offer from arrayB, you don't want to change the HTML, you want to set the src attribute of the img tag,

```
function ShowInitialBrand() {
  $('#BrandWinlist > img').each(function(i, img) {
   random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
//Assign Variable to generate random Brands
var Brand = BrandNameArray.splice(random_BrandIndex, 1)[0];
$(img).attr({'src':Brand,'data-index':random_BrandIndex}).show();
  });
}

function selectBrand(flag) {
// assuming this is a callback function for the event handler, $(this) would be the image that's clicked.
  selectedOffer = $(this).attr('data-index');

  console.log("selectedOffer: " + selectedOffer);

  $("#P_Description").attr('src',selectedOffer);
}
```

Comment: ok, but  at this point, i have tried it out. The 2nd array generates an independent image in contrary to the image generated in the 1st array. Meaning, when img/Brand/A.png is clicked from the first array, the img/Offer/C.png is shown  when rightfully, img/Offer/A.png should be shown. And both images when clicked are sowing the same images from the 2nd array

Comment: You need to store the index for each image separately. When your `each` loop runs, it changes the random_BrandIndex. Then, the click handler uses that to determine what image to show. That means you could show 5 images from arrayA, and it'll always show the index of the last one in arrayB. You can store the index in the element, and get it when clicked so you get the same image as the clicked one.

Comment: I don't really follow you. So if i have to store, i will have a variable: e.g "var storeSelectedOffer" and how should i be referencing that?

Comment: just updated the answer assuming that selectBrand is an event handler. You don't want to store the variable in the JS file because you'll have to know the relationship between the offers and the variable. You could also consider getting the src of the clicked offer, changing the file path from `lib/img/Brands/a.png` to lib/img/Offers/a.png` since their named the same.... That might be easier. You wouldn't need the second array, and you wouldn't need to deal with making sure the array's lined up perfectly.

Comment: selectBrand is an event handler. If i were to follow this method, then nothing is shown. The $("#P_description") will be blanked. sorry, i am just not getting this.